# Sum array value regarding column name in multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

Below the array  i have to format array according to their name which is in `[c]` index

`// $name = $array[result][0][_id][c];`

i want to sum data regarding their name (ex:Maharashtra & Goa) with their pl value

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [c] => Maharashtra & Goa
                            [d] => MongoDate Object
                                (
                                    [sec] => 1412746200
                                    [usec] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [pl] => 107369655
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [c] => unknown
                            [d] => MongoDate Object
                                (
                                    [sec] => 1412659800
                                    [usec] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [pl] => 69356849
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [c] => Maharashtra & Goa
                            [d] => MongoDate Object
                                (
                                    [sec] => 1412832600
                                    [usec] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [pl] => 22320916
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [c] => unknown
                            [d] => MongoDate Object
                                (
                                    [sec] => 1412746200
                                    [usec] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [pl] => 8397870
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [c] => Bihar & Jharkhand
                            [d] => MongoDate Object
                                (
                                    [sec] => 1412746200
                                    [usec] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [pl] => 4278330
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [c] => unknown
                            [d] => MongoDate Object
                                (
                                    [sec] => 1412832600
                                    [usec] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [pl] => 4183450
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [c] => Tamil Nadu
                            [d] => MongoDate Object
                                (
                                    [sec] => 1412832600
                                    [usec] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [pl] => 4113634
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [c] => Maharashtra & Goa
                            [d] => MongoDate Object
                                (
                                    [sec] => 1412487000
                                    [usec] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [pl] => 3716731
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [c] => Maharashtra & Goa
                            [d] => MongoDate Object
                                (
                                    [sec] => 1412659800
                                    [usec] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [pl] => 1203054
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [c] => unknown
                            [d] => MongoDate Object
                                (
                                    [sec] => 1412573400
                                    [usec] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [pl] => 554806
                )

        )

    [ok] => 1
)
```

// Desired array
//  pl will be sum of their name

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Maharashtra & Goa
            [pl] => 134610356
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => unknown
            [pl] => 82492975
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bihar & Jharkhand
            [pl] => 4278330
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tamil Nadu
            [pl] => 4113634
        )


)
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// i tried this 
$resultData =array();
foreach($array['result'] as $key=>$val){
            $itemKey = str_replace(' ', '_', $val['_id']['c']); 
                        //$resultData[$itemKey]= $resultData[$itemKey]+$val['pl'];
                        if(isset($resultData[$itemKey])){
                            $resultData[$itemKey][] =array('name'=>$val['_id']['c'],'p1'=>$val['pl']);
                            $resultData[$itemKey]['total'] +=$val['pl'];
                           // $resultData[$itemKey][$i]['pl']+= $val['pl'];
                        }else{
                             $resultData[$itemKey][] =array('name'=>$val['_id']['c'],'p1'=>$val['pl']);
                             $resultData[$itemKey]['total'] =$val['pl'];
                        }

        }

// it produce result 
Array
(
    [Maharashtra_&_Goa] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Maharashtra & Goa
                    [p1] => 107369655
                )

            [total] => 134610356
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Maharashtra & Goa
                    [p1] => 22320916
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Maharashtra & Goa
                    [p1] => 3716731
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Maharashtra & Goa
                    [p1] => 1203054
                )

        )

    [unknown] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => unknown
                    [p1] => 69356849
                )

            [total] => 82492975
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => unknown
                    [p1] => 8397870
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => unknown
                    [p1] => 4183450
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => unknown
                    [p1] => 554806
                )

        )

    [Bihar_&_Jharkhand] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Bihar & Jharkhand
                    [p1] => 4278330
                )

            [total] => 4278330
        )

    [Tamil_Nadu] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Tamil Nadu
                    [p1] => 4113634
                )

            [total] => 4113634
        )

)
```

Comment: you should put this as a revision to your question

Answer (score 1):

You could just use that name index to group those values and finally just add them.

Example:

```
foreach ($array['result'] as $value) {
    if(!isset($resultData[$value['_id']['c']])) { // initialize
        $resultData[$value['_id']['c']] = array('name' => $value['_id']['c'], 'pl' => 0);
    }
    $resultData[$value['_id']['c']]['pl'] += $value['pl']; // sum them
}

$resultData = array_values($resultData); // simple reindex
echo '<pre>';
print_r($resultData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($aggregateResult['result'] as $key=>$val){
            $itemKey = str_replace(' ', '_', $val['_id']['c']); 
                        $resultData[$itemKey]= $resultData[$itemKey]+$val['pl'];


        }
//will produce in key value 
Array
(
    [unknown] => 82492975
    [Maharashtra_&_Goa] => 134610356
    [Bihar_&_Jharkhand] => 4278330
    [Tamil Nadu] => 4113634

)
```